# jQuery not working fully in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari

I have read through the other posts relating to jQuery and Safari and the issues others are having do not seem to be applicable to mine. I am using the latest version of jQuery, and dreamweaver is not catching any mistakes with the javascript. I am in desperate need to find out why this is not working. It works fine in chrome and firefox (and unfortunately I can not test it out for IE at the moment)

```
<script src="../../zoom/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../zoom/epic-image-zoom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.my-image').epicZoom( {largeImage: '../../images/large/domestic_musings/Gaylen-Beyond_zoom.jpg', magnification: 1} );
});

</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header"> </div>
  <!--End "header"--> 

<div class="center"><img src="../../images/large/domestic_musings/Gaylen&amp;Beyond.jpg" alt="Gaylen and Beyond - large image " width="921" height="718" class="my-image" /></div>
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What's not happening that should? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Have you validated your HTML?  Invalid HTML explains most cross-browser issues.  Although, you never explained what issue(s) you're having, so I have no idea.

Comment: If the only thing you're doing is calling this `epicZoom` plugin, it looks like the problem is with the plugin, not jQuery

Comment: Dreamweaver just parses to vaidate your sintax, not the execution. Does Safari has a developer tool like Chrome and Firefox (Firebug)? Try to use it to see what is your error.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `onload` event since you are manipulating large images. The dom ready event fires when dom becomes ready not images, so you might want to try this instead:

```
jQuery(window).load(function($){
  $('.my-image').epicZoom( {largeImage: '../../images/large/domestic_musings/Gaylen-Beyond_zoom.jpg', magnification: 1} );
});
```

Comment: I apologize. I am new to javascript/jQuery. The (window) .load makes the the script not work in any browser. The HTML has been validated and is fine. The feature is supposed to create a square hover that magnifies the image by 2. In Safari, the the square shows up, but does not magnify. It works just fine in the other browsers. I will see what I can do about a developer tool in Safari.

Comment: I appreciate the advice. It appears that the problem is that the plugin is not working on the latest version of Safari.

Comment: If you trace the value of magnifierImg2.width() in epic-image-zoom.js you'll find that it will be 250 in safari. In IE, it will be the size of your original image, and after magnifierImg2.width(magnifierImg2.width() * options.magnification); it changes according to the magnification.

Comment: by 250, I mean whatever you set options.size to.

Comment: after some digging, found out that epic zoom does not wok on safari when used with bootstrap carousel. Turns out there is something about the css that makes bootstrap carousel work, that makes epic zoom not work in safari. I ran it through a css validator, and there are just too many errors for me to fix by hand 0_0

Answer (score 0):

Going to post @sparky's comment here instead so that people actually see it. This was the fix for me. jQuery events were not firing in Safari (but they were on other browsers). I went to the W3C HTML validator, fixed the errors, and that fixed the problem.

> Have you validated your HTML? Invalid HTML explains most cross-browser
>   issues. Although, you never explained what issue(s) you're having, so
>   I have no idea. – Sparky Jul 17 '12 at 19:30